# What is the right npm name to write in the package.json file?

Tags: javascript, regex, npm

I want to publish my library first time on NPM. 
I want it to be public. So in the `package.json` file of my library I have

```
"name": "firstname-lastname/testlib123"
```

so `my first name` - `my last name`/ `my library name in my case it is testlib123`

and I get error:

> Invalid name when I try to publish.

Also in VS code i have this warning:

```
String does not match the pattern of "^(?:@[a-z0-9-*~][a-z0-9-*._~]*/)?[a-z0-9-~][a-z0-9-._~]*$".
```

I don't understand regex.
Where is my mistake ?

Comment: You are creating a *scoped* package - here's [NPM guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages) for that

Comment: I don't understand, how can i make public package ?

Comment: I tried - npm publish --access public i get again private package error

Comment: You name contains spaces and the regex doesn't allow spaces

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in the comment, follow [this guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages):

1. Create (if not already done) a user on [NPM website](https://www.npmjs.com/)
2. Your package name should start with `@` and then your ***username*** which you have signed up to NPM with and then the package name, example: `@petar/my-package`
3. The **first** publish should be using this command: `npm publish --access public` and all later published can simply be done with the `npm publish` command.

I have written an [article regarding automating private NPM packages releases](https://dev.to/yaireo/automate-npm-package-publish-git-versioning-5cfp) which I think you should read if you wish to write open-source NPM packages without much hassle when publishing.

---

Regarding your regex, are you sure you pasted it here correctly? I've had to remove one character in order to have it parsed, and here's a [website which explains regexes](http://www.regexplained.co.uk/):

[image]